# Rate of Growth by Rows in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with few financial data by rows for certain time duration, I want to calculate rate of growth for each rows, either in new columns or in a new data frame, data I am working on would look some thing like this,

```
 df.new <- t(freeny.x) # Example dataframe
```

I want to calculate growth rate for each item I.e."lag quarterly revenue","price index", "income level","market potential"

I could do this if the data was in columns like in the example below,

```
 df <- data.frame(date=paste(rep(2000:2017, each=4),"Q",rep(1:4, 18)), GDP= cumsum(sample(c(-0.5, 3), 72, TRUE)))
 df <- df %>% mutate(change=(GDP-lag(GDP,1))/lag(GDP,1)*100)
 df
```

How can I do it with df.new , requesting expert help

Comment: *"data I am working on would look some thing like this"* I don't see any (reproducible and copy&paste-able) data. Did you forget to include sample data?

Comment: df.new <- t(freeny.x) .....  this is the dataframe, 'freeny.x' is preloaded dataframe in r

Comment: My mistake @Vikram; never had come across `freeny.x` before... go figure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity purposes I took only first 6 columns of the dataframe, then we can do

```
(df[, 2:ncol(df)] -  df[,-ncol(df)])/df[,-ncol(df)] * 100

#                           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#lag quarterly revenue -0.045473 -0.011260  0.267194 -0.020987  1.072278
#price index           -0.165606 -0.270726 -0.082313 -0.968717 -0.315935
#income level           0.076961  0.095098  0.160175  0.169507  0.244088
#market potential       0.026215  0.031603  0.024658  0.019260  0.017715
```

This will return `n-1` columns if you need the first column with `NA`, you could `cbind` it

```
cbind(NA, (df[, 2:ncol(df)] -  df[,-ncol(df)])/df[,-ncol(df)] * 100)
```

To be sure the calculation is correct take the first two values from first row

```
(8.7924  - 8.7964)/8.7964 * 100
#[1]-0.045473
```

which gives the same value in row 1 column 1 of final output as shown.

**data**

```
df <- df.new[, 1:6]
df
#                         [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]
#lag quarterly revenue  8.7964  8.7924  8.7914  8.8149  8.8130  8.9075
#price index            4.7100  4.7022  4.6894  4.6856  4.6402  4.6255
#income level           5.8211  5.8256  5.8311  5.8405  5.8504  5.8646
#market potential      12.9699 12.9733 12.9774 12.9806 12.9831 12.9854
```